# Using Case Statement with String

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Say i have a string

```
'SomeName'
```

and wanted the values return in a case statement. Can this bedone? Can strings be used in a case statement like so

```
Case 'SomeName' of

   'bobby' : 2;
   'tommy' :19;
   'somename' :4000;
else
   showmessage('Error');
end;
```

Comment: It seems that FreePascal (FPC) already implemented this language feature, I wish Delphi will follow up! [http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=17983.0]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Jcl library you have the StrIndex function `StrIndex(Index, Array Of String)` which works like this:

```
Case StrIndex('SomeName', ['bobby', 'tommy', 'somename']) of 
  0: ..code.. ;//bobby
  1: ..code..;//tommy
  2: ..code..;//somename
else
  ShowMessage('error');
end.
```

Delphi (independent of JCL) provides the same functionality through e.g.

```
function IndexStr(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Integer;
```

or

```
function AnsiIndexStr(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Integer;
```

Comment: Or just use the standard AnsiIndexStr function.

Comment: Or just `IndexStr` in more recent Delphi versions.  (There's also the `-Text` versions if you want case-insensitive comparisons.)

Comment: I suppose it's `end;` and not `end.` ?

Answer (score 41):

The Delphi [`Case Statement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements) only supports ordinal types. So you cannot use strings directly.

But exist another options like

- build a function which returns a Integer (hash) based on a string
- using generics and anonymous methods ( [A generic case for strings](http://delphi.fosdal.com/2010/12/generic-case-for-strings.html))
- using a function which receive an array of strings ([Making a case for Strings, the sane way](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=706))
- and so on.

Answer (score 22):

@Daniel's answer pointed me in the right direction, but it took me a while to notice the "Jcl Library" part and the comments about the standard versions.

In [at least] XE2 and later, you can use:

```
Case IndexStr('somename', ['bobby', 'tommy', 'somename', 'george']) of 
  0: ..code..;                   // bobby
  1: ..code..;                   // tommy
  2: ..code..;                   // somename
 -1: ShowMessage('Not Present'); // not present in array
else
  ShowMessage('Default Option'); // present, but not handled above
end;
```

This version is case-sensitive, so if the first argument was 'SomeName' it would take the `not present in array` path. Use `IndexText` for case-insensitive comparison.

For older Delphi versions, use `AnsiIndexStr` or `AnsiIndexText`, respectively.

Kudos to @Daniel, @The_Fox, and @afrazier for most of the components of this answer.

Comment: IndexStr & AnsiIndexStr are usable also in in Delphi 2007. Unit StrUtils.

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiiice

Answer (score 5):

Works on D7 and Delphi Seattle,

```
uses StrUtils (D7) system.Ansistring (Delphi Seattle) system.StrUtils (Berlin 10.1)

case AnsiIndexStr(tipo, ['E','R'] )   of
      0: result := 'yes';
      1: result := 'no';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it uses System.StrUtils

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  cCaseStrings : array [0..4] of String = ('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
var
  LCaseKey : String;
begin
  LCaseKey := 'one';
  case IndexStr(LCaseKey, cCaseStrings) of
    0: ShowMessage('0');
    1: ShowMessage('1');
    2: ShowMessage('2');
    else ShowMessage('-1');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used AnsiStringIndex and works, but if you can convert to number without problems:

```
try
  number := StrToInt(yourstring);
except
  number := 0;
end;
```